# JavaScript: equivalent regex as PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a regular expression to find the next word of given word 'on' in string for php:

```
(?<=\bon\s)(\w+)
```

It works perfectly for PHP but for js it gives following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\bon\s)(\w+)/:
>   Invalid group

What is the equivalent regex for javascript?

Comment: remove the '/' at the start and ending of the pattern.

Comment: I tried with removing '/' but it didn't work.

Comment: @Pakspul - the `/` at the start and end are part of JS's regex literal syntax, not part of the actual pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`(?<=\bon\s)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). PHP's regular expression  engine (PCRE) supports those, but JavaScript's regular expression engine doesn't.

While it's not possible to write  an exactly similar regex, you can still achieve this using the following regex:

```
\bon\s(\w+)
```

Unlike in the original regex, `\bon\s` consumes characters. But you can still extract the results using a capturing group `(\w+)`.

Usage:

```
var str = 'foo on bar';
var matches = str.match(/\bon\s(\w+)/);
var result = matches[1] // bar
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EBuT/)

Comment: @GaneshKunwar Huh? I didn't give a solution in this answer. I was explaining why your regex didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As Amal Murali explains it, there is no equivalent with Javascript regex. However you can write:

```
\bon\s(\w+)
```

and extract the first capturing group.

Comment: Thanks Casimir for your answer, but it gives two words including 'on'. I need a word after 'on'.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar: this is the reason why you must **extract** the capturing group from the match result. Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression